# Why is the protocol defined twice in Apple's sample code?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I am looking at Apple's sample code for [lazy table image loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Listings/Classes_ParseOperation_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Classes_ParseOperation_h-DontLinkElementID_9). I see that they have two lines starting with `@protocol ParseOperationDelegate`. Why do they do this twice? All the documentation on Objective C protocols I've looked at do not tell you to do it twice.

```
@class AppRecord;

@protocol ParseOperationDelegate;

//@interface ParseOperation : NSOperation <NSXMLParserDelegate>
@interface ParseOperation : NSOperation
{
@private
    id <ParseOperationDelegate> delegate;

    NSData          *dataToParse;

    NSMutableArray  *workingArray;
    //AppRecord       *workingEntry;
    //NSMutableString *workingPropertyString;
    //NSArray         *elementsToParse;
    //BOOL            storingCharacterData;
}

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data delegate:(id <ParseOperationDelegate>)theDelegate;

@end

@protocol ParseOperationDelegate
- (void)didFinishParsing:(NSArray *)appList;
- (void)parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@protocol ParseOperationDelegate;` line is not defining the protocol.  It's a *forward declaration*.  Basically it's saying that "a protocol called `ParseOperationDelegate` exists and is defined somewhere else in the code".

They do this so that the compiler will not die with an error on the line that goes `id <ParseOperationDelegate> delegate;`.  The alternative would be to have the entire protocol definition placed before the interface definition (which personally I think would be a better solution in this case).

In such a simple case as this one I think there is little point in having the forward declaration.  But you can easily imagine a more complex case where perhaps the protocol definition lives in its own header file (or in the header file for some other class).  In a case like that, using a forward declaration allows you to avoid having to `#import` the protocol's header file into your class's header.  It's a small difference, really, but it can be useful.